# center align text with special characters in fpdf

Tags: php, fpdf

I am using fpdf to generate pdf file, and like to align text center.

```
$pdf->SetTextColor(0,42,92);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',24);
$course = "This & that";         
$wi = $pdf->GetStringWidth( $course);
$startPoint = (($pdf->w)/2)-($wi/2);
$pdf->SetXY($startPoint, 195); 
$pdf->Cell($wi, 0, $course, 0, 0, 'C');
```

Everything works fine if i replace $course with

```
$course = "This that";
```

I guess '&' in the string is causing problem. Would be great if anyone figured this out.

Comment: What happens when you have '&' in the line you mentioned?

Comment: center alignment doesnt work. i think its something to do with special characters. i also added few other characters like ' '' and got same result.

Comment: I need to see your complete code because I feel it is inconsistent to the manual given at this [link](http://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/demos/tfpdf-demo/). Go through it and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this change

```
$pdf->Cell($wi, 0, iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252', $course), 0, 0, 'C');
```